# What side do you use Uniq in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

In my rails app I have 2 models `Profile` and `Skill`.

`Profile` has_and_belongs_to_many `Skill` and can only have one time the same `Skill`.

`Skill` has_and_belongs_to_many `Profile`. If we respect the first relation, it should therefore not have more than once the same `Profile`.

When I create my join table I have two possibilities:

```
rails g migration CreateProfilesSkillsJoinTable profiles:uniq skills
```

or

```
rails g migration CreateProfilesSkillsJoinTable profiles skills:uniq
```

The first option will generate

```
class CreateProfilesSkillsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :profiles, :skills do |t|
      t.index [:profile_id, :skill_id], unique: true
      # t.index [:skill_id, :profile_id]
    end
  end
end
```

The second will generate

```
class CreateProfilesSkillsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :profiles, :skills do |t|
      # t.index [:profile_id, :skill_id]
      t.index [:skill_id, :profile_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make the index unique :

```
add_index :something, [:profile_id, :skill_id], unique: true
```

First first rule is verified (you can get `1:2` only once). Note that even with an habtm, you'll tend to create your relation the same way (`profile.skills << skill`), you just need to ensure `skill.profiles << profile` does not creates unwanted relations

Comment: I don't understand when you say `1:2` only once? Actually I'm not sure to see the difference on changing `:profile_id` with `:skill_id`.

Comment: meaning, ids, as an example profile_id=1 / skill_id: 2, only once. and yep, there's no difference. Re-reading it all, you actually have it all, I'm now unsure to understand exactly your issue

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. But if we do the opposite index `t.index [:skill_id, :profile_id], unique: true` it will allow only once `2:1` what is the same than `1:2`. Am I wrong?

Comment: ahha actually I was puzzled by this very question, as I've used habtm for self referential (in this case, it would be an issue). But not here, no difference, profile_id will always refers to profiles, skill_id will always refers to skills. so `profile_id1:skill_id_2` is the same as `skill_id_2:profile_id1` — or i'm shamely missing the point